# How to escape quotes in jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I need help to escape quotes in jinja2 :

{% set info = "or bb cc" %}

I want to produce the following output from the above string:

Expected output:  or "bb" "cc".  How do I achieve this?

I tried splitting the input string and tried to concatenate with ' " ' but, Jinja2 is replacing
" with "

```
{% set ns = namespace(tmp_str = "") %}
{% set lst = info.split(' ') %}
{% for itm in lst %}
  {% if itm == "or" %}
     {% set ns.tmp_str = ns.tmp_str + itm %}
  {% else %}
       {% set ns.tmp_str =  ns.tmp_str  +  '"' + itm  + '"'  %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{ ns.tmp_str|e }}
```

Output seen:  Is having characters like: & # 34 ; in place of "

Expected output: or "bb" "cc"

Comment: Output seen: or&#34;bb&#34;&#34;cc&#34;

Comment: How are you printing the output? its working for me

Comment: I am printing as:  {{ns.tmp_str}}

Comment: Output on the screen seen as: or&#34;bb&#34;&#34;cc&#34;

Comment: Looks like some HTML format is being displayed on the screen

Comment: I think it is displayed as HTML code:  https://www.codetable.net/decimal/34

Comment: Try marking it as safe : `{{ ns.tmp_str | safe }}`

Comment: Tried {{ ns.tmp_str | safe }} , but  still prints it as decimal codes for character "